# Alternatives to the "unique" function when looking for indexes of the unique values (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Let's assume I have an array, `array1`, as follows:

```
array1 = [1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5];
```

I'm trying to find the ***first*** index value of each of the unique values in this array.  This is pretty easy to do with the `unique` function:

```
[~,uniqueIndex,~] = unique(array1,'first')
```

which produces the expected output:

```
uniqueIndex =
     1     2     5     7    10
```

I need to perform this action on thousands of very large arrays and the `unique` function has proven itself to be a huge bottleneck in my code.  I was wondering if there are any alternatives that I could use to achieve the same end result (ie. the `uniqueIndex` variable), but with a smaller performance impact.

EDIT: The arrays are sorted and contain integers only.

Comment: It might help to know a little about the arrays in question. Do they contain integers? Are they already sorted?

Comment: @ MrAzzaman They arrays contain integers and are already sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we know that the arrays are already sorted, we can skip some of the checks that the MATLAB `unique` function carries out. The method that MATLAB uses internally is as follows (minus the checks)

```
n = 1:numel(array1);
d = [true,diff(array1)~=0];
uniqueIndex = n(d);
```

This should speed up your code at least a little.